# Website with changeable image source

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to make a website where I can have a picture that changes daily. I need help setting the image source to the variable `imageurl`. Also, making it so that the variable `imageurl` is global.

Let me clarify, I want it so that it will set the variable `imageurl` to a link, that is set by a prompt, then sets the image to `imageurl`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <div align="center">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>picture of the day</title>
         <h1>Jere's picture of the day</h1>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: #8000ff;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            isitjere = prompt("Password?");
            if (isitjere === "thedog")
                alert("password:" + isitjere + " " + "has been accepted");
            editimage = prompt("do you want to change the image?(type yes or no)");
            if (editimage === "yes")
                imageurl = prompt("paste the image url(if you dont have a url for it you can upload it and paste the upload link)");
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">edit</button>
    <img src=imageurl>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you actually have any Java code written yet?

Comment: Java or Javascript?

Comment: under the body tag. it starts at "function myFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

don't know what's your intention.. but here a code snippet working :)
(http://codepen.io/f7o/pen/VjpjOW)

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var isitjere = prompt("Password?");
                if (isitjere === "thedog")
                    alert("password:" + isitjere + " " + "has been accepted");
                var editimage = prompt("do you want to change the image?(type yes or no)");
                if (editimage === "yes")
                    var imageurl = prompt("paste the image url(if you dont have a url for it you can upload it and paste the upload link)");
      console.log(imageurl);
    $("#pic").attr('src',imageurl);
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">edit</button>

  <div align="center">
    <title>picture of the day</title>
    <h1>Jere's picture of the day</h1>
  </div>
  <img id="pic" src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png">

</body>

</html>
```